# ListWeelScrollView: how to put a block?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll

Is it possible to put a block (as the end of the list) for scrolling at a certain point by index?  Googled, unfortunately found nothing.
Not disable scroll, This is not turning off the scroll as a whole, but a block for scrolling to a certain point.  (You can only scroll to this point)

Comment: My builder generates a sheet.  I filter it by dates.  And at build I hide through a condition.  But when scrolling, it goes beyond the limits and scrolls empty values.  I want to put a block before the end of the filtered element so that it doesn't go off the edge of the list.

Comment: I think you can filter the list in that case. Can you include sample demo widget